# how can split the result set array to string in php

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

i need help. i was developed a page in smarty , i got a result set from a query and i need to change the result set to string and stored in text area

my query is given below

```
select val from test
```

my result set is print in var_dump in controller

```
{ [0]=>  array(1) { ["val"]=>  string(1) "c" } [1]=>  array(1) { ["val"]=>  string(3) "c++" } [2]=>  array(1) { ["val"]=>  string(4) "java" } [3]=>  array(1) { ["val"]=>  string(3) "PHP" } }
```

i need to change in to sting like  `c,c++,java,PHP`

the changing function is preformed only controller

ple help me.. and thk adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach for that. See more information here - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php .

Example -

```
$array = Array("333", "222", "111");

foreach($array as $string) {
    echo $string.'<br />';
}
```

Another solution would be to use implode.

See more information here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php and again a small example -

```
    $array = Array("333", "222", "111");

    $strings = implode(",", $array); // comma in first quotes are seperator, you can set it also to " " for a single space.

    echo $strings; // In this case it will output 333,222,111 if you would set it to empty space then it would output 333 222 11
```

**EDIT:**

For writing in file you must use file functions.

Check this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

example -

```
    // your file
    $file = 'sample.txt';
    $array = Array("333", "222", "111");
    // Add all strings to $content.
    foreach($array as $string) {
        $content .= $string.'<br />';
    }
    // write everything in file
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

**Suggestion:**

When you are writing SQL queries, I would suggest that you already now start learning to write them correctly, so they are easier to read.

For example, your query -

```
select val from test
```

Could be changed to -

```
SELECT `val` FROM `test`
```

which is alot easier to read and understand.

Comment: foreach is correct but the controller page how can i made and post to the tpl file. ple help

Comment: i need smarty tpl file sir. not txt file.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to join all array with some delimeters, then use implode.
Example:

```
$arr = array("hi", "peter!", "how", "are", "you");
echo implode(" ", $arr) . "?";

//output
// hi peter! how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string separated by commas, you must use the implode function

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

> glue: Defaults to an empty string. This is not the preferred usage of implode() as glue would be the second parameter and thus, the bad prototype would be used.
>   pieces:The array of strings to implode.
>
> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Example

```
$array = Array("333", "222", "111");
$string = explode(',', $array);
```

returns

```
"333,222,111"
```

if you want spaces:

```
$string = explode(' ', $array);
```

returns

```
"333 222 111"
```